# Trying to calculate the normal derivative of a function on the sphere but getting an 'inverted' representation?

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-geometry

The normal derivative of a function $u(x)$ on the surface of a sphere of radius $r$, i.e. $r = |x|$ can be represented in spherical polar coordinates as
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} & = \nu \cdot \nabla u \\ 
& = \hat r \cdot \nabla \\ 
& = \hat r \cdot \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \hat r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} \hat \theta + \frac{1}{r^2\sin \theta}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \phi} \hat \phi\right) \\
& = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}.
\end{align}
$$

I want to obtain the same result using a different approach so I did the following:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} & = \nu \cdot \nabla u \\
& = \frac{x}{|x|} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}
\end{pmatrix} \\
& = \mathbf{\left(\frac{x_1}{r}, \frac{x_2}{r}, \frac{x_3}{r} \right)} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
So this should be equal to the representation for the normal derivative above, i.e. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$. Using the chain rule on $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ I get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} & = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}\frac{d x_1}{d r} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2}\frac{d x_2}{d r} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_3}\frac{d x_3}{d r} \\
& = \frac{dx}{dr} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Then $r = |x| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$ means $x_1 = \sqrt{r^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}$. This gives $\displaystyle \frac{d x_1}{dr} = \frac{r}{x_1}$ and so
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = \mathbf{\left(\frac{r}{x_1}, \frac{r}{x_2}, \frac{r}{x_3} \right)} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2},
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So the numerator and denominator are switched when I take this approach! Where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you derive $x_1$ you should consider that $x_2$ and $x_3$ depend on $r$ too.

Comment: Ah yes, not it works, thanks!